# ui-grid both sort icon visible at initial page load

Tags: angular, ui-grid

How can I display sort up/down icon on initial load, like the image below.[sort up/down icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgRrm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your own headerCellTemplate and add it to the column/s you want to change in the column definition, adding the property **headerCellTemplate**.

The default headerCellTemplate is provided in the following [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/src/templates/ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell.html)

Comment: when a column is not sorted, it does not show an icon. But I require an icon to be displayed indicating that the column can be sorted. The css has a class -
.ui-grid-icon-blank::before { width: 1em; content: ' '; }
but on changing the content of the icon, the icon does not appear due to another class ui-grid-invisible applied on it. On removal of that class the priorities are visible as well, which is not required.